# POST form and prevent response

Tags: html, forms, post

I have the following form:

```
<form method="post" action="http://domain.com/api.json?param=value"></form>
```

On submission of this form, this will replace my document with a response from `http://domain.com/api.json`.

Is it possible to POST this form, but prevent receiving a response, and keep the existing HTML with the `form`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send an HTTP 204 No Content [response](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) instead of the usual 200 OK response.

> 10.2.5 204 No Content
>
> The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to return an
>   entity-body, and might want to return updated metainformation. The
>   response MAY include new or updated metainformation in the form of
>   entity-headers, which if present SHOULD be associated with the
>   requested variant.
>
> If the client is a user agent, it SHOULD NOT change its document view
>   from that which caused the request to be sent. This response is
>   primarily intended to allow input for actions to take place without
>   causing a change to the user agent's active document view, although
>   any new or updated metainformation SHOULD be applied to the document
>   currently in the user agent's active view.
>
> The 204 response MUST NOT include a message-body, and thus is always
>   terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use AJAX (XMLHttpRequest in this example) to submit the post

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://domain.com/api.json?param=value", true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Before hand, if you need. You can grab your param value and encode it:

```
var val = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("param").value);
```

then the second line would be more like:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://domain.com/api.json?param="+val, true);
```

Otherwise, any sort of submitting from a `form` will load a page. A hack would be to put it in a iframe thats hidden, and just delete the iframe when done.

Comment: That values to encode the value (which might include special characters) to make it safe for inserting into a URI, and it sends the data in the URI instead of the request body (where it belongs in a POST request).

Comment: "You could just use AJAX or XMLHttpRequest" is like saying "You could just drive or use a car".

Comment: @Quentin - yes i know, but you can drive, or more specifically drive a car (not a truck). I was just saying that because i know there is also a jQuery way of doing it that actually uses ajax syntax... So, there are two ways.

Comment: @Quentin - And yes, again, there might be some encoding issues depending on the data being sent and the requirements of OP. But, with out changing the server, I dont know of another way.

Comment: [`encodeURICompoent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)