# how to open same page onsubmit?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have html form whose action is a php script. php code basically replaces the file. 
HTML code:

```
<form name="input" action="//copy.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return alertbox();">                        

 <input type="hidden" name="path1" value=path to image 1/>
 <input type="hidden" name="path2" value='path to image 2' />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Copy image"/>                

</form>
```

Php code:

```
if isset($_POST['submit']))
   {       
    $image1 = $_POST['path1']; 
    $image2 = $_POST['path2'];
    copy($image1, $image2);
    }
```

?>

Now when I click submit, a alert box opens that "file is updated successfully" and when I click ok on it, a blank page load. How can I avoid loading the blank page? I want to stay on the same page after clicking submit with pop up msg.

**SOLUTION**

As I don't see "Answer your own question" option, I am posting solution here. 
This link [POST form and prevent response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072648/post-form-and-prevent-response), gives you textual answer to the question. While I providing the answer by code.

So basically, it very simpl. Just put

```
header("HTTP/1.0 204 No Response");
```

in the php file and it will work successfully on all browser, without opening new page. This will avoid use of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Leave action empty.

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

Then check if posted using isset function

```
if(isset($_POST)){
...
}
```

Comment: No. That will load a new page from the same URL.

Answer (score 0):

This will keep you on the same page after submit button..

```
<form name="input" action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return alertbox();">

 <input type="hidden" name="path1" value=path to image 1/>
 <input type="hidden" name="path2" value='path to image 2' />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Copy image"/>

</form>
```

But now, your image(s) may not be loaded. Maybe it will work, maybe not. If not, you will need to resolve functions which may reside in `copy.php` file. Since we dont know whats in that file, its hard to answer your question correctly, but.. you may try this "blind" shot..

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
       {       
        //include "//copy.php"; // this file probably contains functions, so lets load functions first IF needed.. 
        $image1 = $_POST['path1']; 
        $image2 = $_POST['path2'];
        copy($image1, $image2);

        }
```

Comment: No. That will load a new page from the same URL.

Comment: @Quentin My guess is that alertbox() is a pure "Do you want to proceed?" message nothing else. Since PHP action calls copy.php file its kinda obvious. Otherwise, jquery would call that file, not PHP action. But irrelevant.

Comment: So it can only be done only using jquery, right? or there is way in which I can avoid using jquery (because I don't know it).

Comment: I have put solution in my question. thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the type on the input:

```
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Copy image"/>
```

to

```
 <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Copy image"/>
```

`<input type="button" />` won't submit a form by default (check all browsers to be sure).

`<input type="submit">` by default, the  tag in which the submit input is, is submitted. If you still want to use this, you will have to override the input submit/button's functionality with an event.preventDefault(). In that case, you need:

```
$('#submit').click(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
     //Do whatever you need to 

   //Submit if needed: document.forms[0].submit();
});
```

For further details refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290215/difference-between-input-type-button-and-input-type-submit)

Answer (score 0):

```
action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>
```

Comment: I did that and put it above html, but it still loads another page.